# Provide your own coefficients in Pandas regression

Tags: python, pandas, regression

I am generating the model using Pandas OLS.predict

```
mod = smf.ols(formula='response ~ ' + ' + '.join(symbols), data=training)
res = mod.fit()
```

Which I use later for prediction:

```
res.predict(exog=outofsample
```

Is there an easy way to pass my own coefficients to **res** model? I would like to store the coefficients in a JSON file in order to reuse them in my script rather than generating new ones every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to implement save/load the coefficients in `res.params` to a JSON file but the easiest way would be to use the native methods:

```
res.save('results.pickle')
```

Later you can do:

```
import statsmodels.api as smf
res = smf.load('results.pickle')
res.predict(...)
```

Comment: Thanks. I can see that I could easily replace the res.params. Do you know how would I create a new res object? I suspect it would need to have a model as well? I am trying to avoid using the build-in save() function as I need to use JSON here.

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand, can you post a new question with the expected input and output?